# adb not available on fedora linux

Tags: android, adb, fedora

I just switched from Ubuntu to Fedora but I have a problem with installing ADB, before that I installed adb on my Ubuntu and worked normally with it, but in the process of working I encountered some problems. I was struggling with Ubuntu so I decided to switch to using Fedora.

i installed adb on my fedora linux with below command
`sudo dnf install android-tools`
i got the successful installation message but when i connect my phone to my pc no message appears i have enabled debug mode on my android phone it worked before on windows and ubuntu, but not working on fedora, anyone have the same problem as me, please guide me how to fix it, thanks.
`Last metadata expiration check: 1:49:01 ago on Sun 28 May 2023 10:21:47 PM +07. Package android-tools-1:33.0.3p1-1.fc38.x86_64 is already installed. Dependencies resolved. Nothing to do. Complete!`

Comment: Unless adb server is running you won't get a message on the device to authorize a new PC. Usually adb server is not started as daemon but on-demand. So execute `adb devices` on Fedora to see if adb starts and your device is found.